# Why isn't mongoose custom error handling not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to handle the required validation error in order to make the error message more readable before being passed to the frontend:

```
UserSchema
  .post('save', function (error, doc, next) {
    console.log(error.errors);
    if (error.name === 'ValidationError' && error.errors.academicRole.kind === 'required') {
      console.log('custom error');
      next(new Error('Academic Role is required.'));
    } else {
      next(error);
    }
  });
```

This code causes User's save callback to be called with error being an empty object when the academicRole property is missing; why isn't the save callback called with an error object containing the custom message?

Answer (score 0):

Validation errors should be checked in the [post('validate')](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) hook.

If there is validation error, the save() method and associated hooks pre('save') and post('save') will not get called.

```
UserSchema
  .post('validate', function (err, doc, next) {
    console.log(err.errors);
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError' && err.errors.academicRole.kind === 'required') {
      console.log('custom error');
      next(new Error('Academic Role is required.'));
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Using that code, nothing is logged. Mongoose's docs also seem to indicate the error is handled in post-save under Error Handling Middleware.

Comment: I just had a look at the documentation. It says - "*Validation is asynchronously recursive; when you call Model#save, sub-document validation is executed as well. If an error occurs, your Model#save callback receives it*". As far as I understand, it means that the error will neither show up in `post('validate')` or `post('save')` hooks. It will actually show up in the `save()` method itself. Please see the [documentation here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

Comment: What might be the problem with the post validate not being called is that the value I am validating is `undefined` which mongoose by-design only validates with the built-in `required` validator, which is the validator I am trying to intercept.